# Eclipse not showing images in JavaDoc view

Tags: eclipse

For some reason images are not visible in my Javadoc view of Eclipse.

[no images visible http://shlinkr.com/images/CropperCapture-12.Png](http://shlinkr.com/images/CropperCapture-12.Png)

But the *same* Javadocs work perfectly fine in a browser:

[images visible http://shlinkr.com/images/CropperCapture-13.Png](http://shlinkr.com/images/CropperCapture-13.Png)

Has something gone a little screwy with my instance of Eclipse? Do I need to change a setting or something? Ideas?

**Update:** In this instance I'm using 3.4.1 (Ganymede), but I just opened the same project up in 3.3 Europa and it has the same problem.

Comment: I do confirm you will have this issue unless you use 3.5Mx eclipse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you manage to have any image displayed in an eclipse javadoc ?

Because it seems to be a [a known limitation which recently got fixed in the 3.5 stream](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg23081.html)...

So... what eclipse are you using ? 3.4 ? 3.4.1 ? 3.5Mx ?

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll wait for Galileo. It isn't super important, just amazing that such a feature has taken this long to work in such a mature product.

Comment: @Scott: I will check if it has been retro-fitted and fixed in 3.4.2, which will be release before 3.5 Galileo.

Answer (score 0):

Using `@docRoot` annotation

```
<img src="{@docRoot}/logo.png">
```

See more java  documentation please here